# How to use std::unordered_map::insert_or_assign

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I implement the std::unordered_map::insert_or_assign method?

Document: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert_or_assign

***Parameters:***

***k*** -   the key used both to look up and to insert if not found

***hint***  -   iterator to the position before which the new element will be 
                inserted

***obj***   -   the value to insert or assign

I am confused as to what hint is suppose to be?

I create a came_from unordered map with Coord classes. (I believe the Coord class is irrelevant here, but if you find necessary, comment, then I will show code). What is the hint parameter suppose to be in this situation?

```
unordered_map<Coord, Coord>& came_from;

Coord start = Coord(0,0);
Coord goal = Coord(1,1);
came_from.insert_or_assign(start, "What is suppose to be here", goal);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hint` is helpful to separate lookup from insertion. It is generally used along with `lower_bound`.

[`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) returns an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) that is not less than (i.e. greater or equal to) value, or last if no such element is found.

This means that it returns the iterator where the key would be if it were already present in the map, irrespective of whether it is present or not.

So `hint` is useful for **ordered** `map`. Although `unordered_map` also has this function, it cannot be used in an effective way as since a useful `hint` cannot be found for it.

So in case of `unordered_map`, you can use the `begin()` or `end()` iterators as a `hint`.

Or as @Caleth mentions, you can just use the overload that does not take a `hint`.

Comment: Rather than giving a nonsense hint, you can also call the overload that doesn't ask for it.

Comment: @Caleth: Updated the answer with your input. Thank you.